# How to make Cloudinary JS product galleries work with hidden elements?

Tags: javascript, html, cloudinary

I'm using several Cloudinary product galleries on the page (see [this page](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/product_gallery_reference)). These product galleries are divided in groups which follow each other in HTML. (so all galleries are divided into several `<div>` sections). I need to embed the page containing these galleries into another page (say, via `<iframe>`). But then I need to show only one group of galleries at once and make the user be able to navigate them.

**Getting to the point**: I need to load the whole page containing these galleries and then hide all of them but one (for example, using `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`. The problem is that this way the containers of the galleries (to which we apply the Cloudinary library methods) are not rendered to the DOM, which causes this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element is probably not rendered to the DOM - something with your layout or CSS definition
at e.<anonymous> (all.js:23)
at all.js:23
at Object.next (all.js:23)
at o (all.js:23)
```

So you can't initiate a gallery in a container with `display: none`. Is there any workaround to avoid this?

UPD: @AditiMadan shared a perfect example of this: https://jsfiddle.net/aditimadan/f54zLxgc/1/ (please take a look at the errors in the console and add a line to set `display: auto` to both galleries after initiating them. You'll see what I'm talking about)

Comment: Is there a webpage where this can be tested? I tried with the display none and it worked: https://jsfiddle.net/aditimadan/f54zLxgc/1/

Comment: @AditiMadan Actually, it doesn't work for the example you've attached. If you take a look at the errors in the console, you'll find the error I'm talking about. One of the 2 galleries (`#my-gallery2`) doesn't have `display: none` and it works fine, but the other one doesn't appear if you set it to `display: auto` via js (after initiating a gallery). I'll update the question to include your fiddle for others